# Springboot Thymeleaf MySql Hibernate trying to pull from database by something other than ID

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a database that stores information and it is associated with a user via a session that gets entered automatically when a user enters the information.  I am trying to get the information to only show information for a specific session.  I cant figure out how to do it on the back end or the front end.  This is my first time asking on here so I apologize if I am not being clear enough.  I am trying to get my MVP going and this is one of the final steps I need.  Below is my controller index and currently only shows all jobs via jobDao.findAll()

```
    @RequestMapping(value="")
    public String index(Model model, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request){
        Integer username =(Integer) session.getAttribute("user_id");
        model.addAttribute("jobs", (jobDao.findAll()));

        return "job/index";
```

This is my controller add that adds the job-

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processJobAdd(@ModelAttribute @Valid Job newJob, HttpSession session, Errors errors, Model model,
                                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("jobTitle", "Add Job Title");
            model.addAttribute("address", "Add Address");
            model.addAttribute("jobCategory", "Select Job Category");
            model.addAttribute("jobSummary", "Add Job Summary");
            model.addAttribute("location", "Add Location");
            model.addAttribute("schedule", "Add Schedule");
            model.addAttribute("positionType", "Add Position Type");
            model.addAttribute("numOfPositions", "Add Number of Positions");
            model.addAttribute("dressCode", "Add Dress Code");
            model.addAttribute("payRate", "Add Pay Rate");
            model.addAttribute("closingDate", "Add Closing Date");
            return "job/add";
        }

        Integer name =(Integer) session.getAttribute("user_id");
        System.out.println(name +" is session name");
        newJob.setSession(name);

        jobDao.save(newJob);

        return "redirect:/job";
    }
```

This is my Dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface JobDao extends CrudRepository<Job, Integer> {

}
```

This is my table in my .HTML

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Job Category</th>
            <th>Job Summary</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Schedule</th>
            <th>Position Type</th>
            <th>Number of Positions</th>
            <th>Dress Code</th>
            <th>Pay Rate</th>
            <th>Closing Date</th>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="job : ${jobs}">            <td><a th:href="'job/edit/' + ${job.id}" th:text="Edit"></a></td>
            <td th:text="${job.jobTitle}"></td>            <td th:text="${job.address}"></td>
            <td th:text="${job.jobCategory}"></td>            <td th:text="${job.jobSummary}"></td>
            <td th:text="${job.location}"></td>            <td th:text="${job.schedule}"></td>
            <td th:text="${job.positionType}"></td>            <td th:text="${job.numOfPositions}"></td>
            <td th:text="${job.dressCode}"></td>            <td th:text="${job.payRate}"></td>
            <td th:text="${job.closingDate}"></td>        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is a picture of my MySql database that shows the session Integer I am trying to show.

[Database Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64lnF.png)

If the picture is not clear here is what the exported table looks like

```
</pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas><!--- Database: 'stlyouthjobs' -->
-<database name="stlyouthjobs"><!-- Table job -->

-<table name="job">
<column name="id">3</column>
<column name="address">1234 home</column>
<column name="closing_date">none</column>
<column name="dress_code">Casual</column>
<column name="job_category">Shipping</column>
<column name="job_summary">work</column>
<column name="job_title">Manager</column>
<column name="location">Home</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">1</column>
<column name="pay_rate">12</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">to much</column>
<column name="session">1</column>
</table>

-<table name="job">
<column name="id">4</column>
<column name="address">654 Home</column>
<column name="closing_date">None</column>
<column name="dress_code">Casual</column>
<column name="job_category">Inventory</column>
<column name="job_summary">Work</column>
<column name="job_title">Manager</column>
<column name="location">Home</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">1</column>
<column name="pay_rate">12</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">to much</column>
<column name="session">1</column>
</table>
-<table name="job">
<column name="id">5</column>
<column name="address">987 Home</column>
<column name="closing_date">Yesterday</column>
<column name="dress_code">Cloths</column>
<column name="job_category">Shipping</column>
<column name="job_summary">Work</column>
<column name="job_title">Manager</column>
<column name="location">Home</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">1</column>
<column name="pay_rate">15</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">to much</column>
<column name="session">1</column>
</table>
-<table name="job">
<column name="id">6</column>
<column name="address">195 Home</column>
<column name="closing_date">tomorrow</column>
<column name="dress_code">Cloths</column>
<column name="job_category">Register</column>
<column name="job_summary">Work</column>
<column name="job_title">Clerk</column>
<column name="location">Home</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">2</column>
<column name="pay_rate">16</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">All</column>
<column name="session">2</column>
</table>
-<table name="job">
<column name="id">7</column>
<column name="address">123566</column>
<column name="closing_date">None</column>
<column name="dress_code">None</column>
<column name="job_category">Home</column>
<column name="job_summary">Work</column>
<column name="job_title">Job</column>
<column name="location">None</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">1</column>
<column name="pay_rate">10</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">All</column>
<column name="session">2</column>
</table>
-<table name="job">
<column name="id">8</column>
<column name="address">None</column>
<column name="closing_date">None</column>
<column name="dress_code">None</column>
<column name="job_category">All</column>
<column name="job_summary">Work</column>
<column name="job_title">Manager</column>
<column name="location">Some</column>
<column name="num_of_positions">1</column>
<column name="pay_rate">9</column>
<column name="position_type">full-time</column>
<column name="schedule">A lot</column>
<column name="session">3</column>
</table>
</database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

Comment: OK but... what is your question?

Comment: How would I pull from the database by session instead of ID?